# Highlight the details of a window under cursor

Tags: window, cursor, spy

I need a tool that displays detailed information about the Win32 window which is currently under the mouse cursor. The info I need at minimum:

- Class name
- Caption name
- Window style
- Window extended style
- Window procedure address

I know that Spy++ does a similar job. But Spy++ wouldn't help because I need to spy for menus. And essentially, a menu disappears when I choose to spy for it.

Any other tool that comes to mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it: http://www.dennisbabkin.com/winid